# Add javascript into page from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm making webView in Xcode and i want to add javascript code into any page content which user loads.So is there a way to add javascript code into page content? 
Like browser add-on which adds javascript code in every page user enters,and ads appears from page,not from browser.
I have this code which show me the whole page(which user enters)data in console,now i need to add javascript code to this page content.

`let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in 
let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

p.s. I'm making app in Swift language
 Hope you'll get it.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method in UIWebView.

```
func stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(_ script: String) -> String?
```

Comment: You can call the method from the webview. Call it where ever you want.